# Infinite loop while reading a file to run a shell script in C

Tags: c, shell, unix

When I try running a file with three or more lines of code it runs in an infinite loop.

This is the function that reads the whole file.

```
// When myShell is called with a Script as Argument
int myShellScript(char filename[100])
{
//    printf("Received Script. Opening %s", filename);
    FILE *fptr;
    char line[200];
    char **args;
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nUnable to open file.");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

//        printf("\nFile Opened. Parsing. Parsed commands displayed first.");
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fptr)!= NULL)
        {
            args= wish_split_line(line);
            wish_execute(args);
        }
    }
    free(args);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 1;
}
```

This is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if(argc == 1)
        wish_loop();
    else if(argc == 2){
        myShellScript(argv[1]);

    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is the test file:

```
path tests
p1.sh
path
p1.sh
ls
exit
```

This is the wish function that is called to execute a command:

```
int wish_launch(char **args)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // Child process
        if (execvp(args[0], args) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "An error has occurred\n");
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        // Error forking
        fprintf(stderr, "An error has occurred\n");
    } else {
        // Parent process
        do {
            waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
    }

    return 1;
}
```

What I have noticed is that once I call the method within a while loop more than three times it caused an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code, except for the misdirection about "shell" when there's no shell involved.  You're testing the return values of **fopen** and **fgets**.  It seems likely the *wish* functions aren't working as you expect, and you get stuck somewhere in there.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden Thank you. I have added the `wish_launch` function that it invoked in the while loop.